# Set JDK home (javac path) in user's gradle.properties

Tags: gradle, javac

I need to specify the path to `javac` in my gradle project. I can do this by adding the following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
options.forkOptions.executable = '/home/mj/lib/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac'
```

The problem is that this file is shared in our repository and I do not want the setting to get pushed there. I tried putting it in my local `gradle.properties` file, but it didn't work. Also setting `gradle.java.home` does not affect this. I guess it's because gradle uses `gradle.java.home` for `java` and not for `javac`, right? I also (hopelessly) tried setting a `gradle.jdk.home` which (not surprisingly) didn't work either!

Is there any place outside the project that is included in build.gradle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your gradle.properties:

```
javacPath=/home/mj/lib/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac
```

In your build.gradle

```
options.forkOptions.executable = project.property('javacPath')
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Although it would be much better not to have this configuration inside `build.gradle`.

Comment: There is a way to put setting in a user's gradle.properties file .... like described here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_cross_compilation

Answer (score 3):

Using a path relative to "java.home" has worked for us. Not elegant, but this does not need another setting. The reason why we need this in the first place is that we build with a JDK that's part of the working copy, not pre-installed with the Jenkins slave. We have no javac/JDK on the slave, just a JRE to run the Jenkins slave. Our `gradlew` in the working copy points to the JDK *next to it*.

```
compileJava {
  options.fork = true
  options.forkOptions.executable = "${System.properties['java.home']}/../bin/javac"
}
```

(Note: At Java run time, `java.home` points to the `$JAVA_HOME/jre` folder within the JDK. That's one below where the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable points to.)

Answer (score 2):

It's closing in on the end of 2021 and there's a much simpler approach now. In your project's root directory add the following to your gradle.properties file (add the file, too, if it doesn't exist):

```
org.gradle.java.home=path/to/jdk
```

Comment: this may go to public when commiting to, e.g., Github. How to deal with sensitive path information?

Comment: @LucasSousa  `.gitignore`, You don't check it into the repo.